# Fixing the last column datatable colreorder

Tags: jquery, datatables

how to fix the last column when using datatable colreorder?

I have tried the below it doesn't work:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "sDom": 'R',
                "oColReorder": {
                    "iFixedColumns":[-1]    
                }
             });
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. People will have to make assumptions or guesses to what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the below solution: 
I have added a div to the last th of the table like the below:

```
<th >First</th>
<th >2</th>
<th >3</th>
<th >4</th>
<th ><div id="theLast">last</div></th>
```

and called the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#theLast").bind("mousedown", function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation(true);
                return;
            }
            );

            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "sDom": 'R'
        });

    });
```

Like this i disabled the last column from colReorder functionality.
To disable the other columns from being dropped after this last column i modified the code 
inside ColReorder.js file like the below:

function modified: _fnMouseUp

i wrote :

```
if (this.s.mouse.toIndex == 4) { // 4 means last  column index 
                    e.stopPropagation(true);
                    return null;
                }
                else
                /* Actually do the reorder */
                this.s.dt.oInstance.fnColReorder(this.s.mouse.fromIndex, this.s.mouse.toIndex);
```

instead of

```
this.s.dt.oInstance.fnColReorder(this.s.mouse.fromIndex, this.s.mouse.toIndex);
```